# How I can display dropdown menu list based on my code and JSON response object?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

I am trying to display a dropdown list based on JSON response object, How I can set it for the following code?
in html

```
<select class="form-control" name="productCategories[]" id="productCategories<?php echo $x; ?>" onchange="getProductData(<?php echo $x; ?>)" >
                                
</select>
```

in javascript

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'php_action/fetchDropdownProductData.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {brandId : brandId},
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(response) { 
                    
            var html = '<option value="">Select Sub Category</option>';
            html += response;
            $("#productCategories"+row).html(html);
                    
                    
                } // /success
            });
```

Log response looks like

```
[{“categories_id”:“1”,“categories_name”:“Monitor”},{“categories_id”:“3”,“categories_name”:“Scanner”}]
```

Comment: *"Log response looks like"* ....that's not json

Comment: [{“categories_id”:“1”,“categories_name”:“Monitor”},{“categories_id”:“3”,“categories_name”:“Scanner”}]

Comment: Edit the question to update that data not drop it in a comment block. Also show us what you tried that isn't working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is an array of category object, you have to loop through your json to create the list of options element, your success function should look like this:

```
success: function (response) {
   var html = '<option value="">Select Sub Category</option>';
   response.forEach(category => {
       html += "<option value='" + category.categories_id + "'>"+ category.categories_name +"</option>"
       $("#productCategories"+row).html(html);
   })
}
```